# Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names in sunbust() r

Tags: r, rows, bind, sunburst-diagram

I was trying to replicate the query to create a sunburst chart in R, but ran into the following error message: `Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names`

Here is the data I used to test the `sunburst()` function: `sequences <- read.csv( system.file("examples/visit-sequences.csv",package="sunburstR") ,header=F ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

im on Rstudio 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you update your version of RStudio.
I have tried this with RStudio version 4.0.3 and it worked fine.

```
library(sunburstR) 
sequences <- read.csv( system.file("examples/visit-sequences.csv",
                                   package="sunburstR") ,
                       header=F ,
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

sunburst(sequences)
```

[Default Sunburst](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTc7T.jpg)